# getElementsByClass returns all values

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm using JSOUP lib to parse a website, when I want to retrieve values with that line of code:
`element.getElementsByClass("s_t").select("a").val("href").text()` I have the desired data. However, when I do that, `element.getElementsByClass("s_t").text()` it returns the value of all `s_t` tags even the previous ones. How can I limit to retrieve just parent `s_t` without browsing interior tags?
`element.getElementsByClass("s_t").select("a").val("href").text()` //returns "hello"
`element.getElementsByClass("s_t").text()` //returns "hello" and "a"
I want to remove that "hello".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:
I just have to add a get(index) method:

```
element.getElementsByClass("s_t").get(2).text()
```